How to tell the difference of "echo", "resonate", and "strike a chord"? Do native speakers often use these three word together?
I read a short passage and confused by the usage of these three words. Here's the passage.

A Ukrainian woman posted on Xiaohongshu(a lifestyle social media platform in China) a picture of her looking tearful alongside her boyfriend. Chinese netizens quickly flooded the comments section with humor and wit.
One comment, "you swan, he frog," resonated widely. It echoes the Chinese saying used to describe someone reaching beyond their ability.
These remarks, though steeped in Chinese humor, struck a chord with people worldwide. The reactions highlight how humor, even when rooted in cultural nuances, can captivate and connect global audiences.


What has the dictionary said about their meanings? Note that 'struck a chord' is an idiom.

"resonate" and "strike a chord" have similar meanings. In fact, the M-W definition of "resonate" uses the latter phrase:

to relate harmoniously : strike a chord

Saying that a comment resonated widely means that many people shared the sentiment expressed by the comment.
"echo" is not really related to this. This definition is:

to be reminiscent of : evoke

So they're just saying that the comment "you swan, he frog" is similar to (perhaps even a translation of) a Chinese saying.
